# On scroll to the page add class to the header menu in react

Tags: html, reactjs

I am using react.js. What I am doing is when the user scrolls the page then I have to add the class to the header menu. I tried below code but it's not working.

I create a file in the public folder and added below the script in the index.html

```
 <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/custom.js"></script>
```

custom.js

```
const header = document.getElementById("header_menu");

const sectionOneOptions = {
  rootMargin: "-200px 0px 0px 0px"
};

const sectionOneObserver = new IntersectionObserver(function(
  entries,
  sectionOneObserver
) {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    if (!entry.isIntersecting) {
      header.classList.add("menuscroll");
    } else {
      header.classList.remove("menuscroll");
    }
  });
},
sectionOneOptions);
```

**Header.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

const HeaderMenu = () => {
    return (
        <header id="header_menu">
        <div className="right-menu float-right">
            <ul>
                <li><Link to={'/'} >Home</Link></li>
                <li><Link to={'/about'} >About Us</Link></li>
                <li><Link to={'/contact'} >Contact Us</Link></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        </header>
        );
  }

  export default HeaderMenu;
```

Comment: on what condition do you want to remove the class `menuscroll`?

Comment: @rotimi-best, When the user scrolls 100 px then I have to add the class to the menu also I want to remove the same class if reach at top

Comment: okay let me update my answer then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One important thing to say is that when using react try your best not to manipulate the DOM yourself, that should be react's job.

In `useEffect`, we listen for the scroll event and then call a function. In that function I am checking if the classname has already been set, if it has then we don't want to update the state to avoid infinity loop, I also check if it the [`pageYOffset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/pageYOffset) greater than or equal to 100px. I do vice versa to remove the classname when we get less than 100px

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const HeaderMenu = () => {
    const [headerClassName, setHeaderClassName] = useState('');

    const handleScroll = (headerClassName) => {
        if (headerClassName !== 'menuscroll' && window.pageYOffset >= 100) {
            setHeaderClassName('menuscroll');
        } else if (headerClassName === 'menuscroll' && window.pageYOffset < 100) {
            setHeaderClassName('');
        }
    }

    React.useEffect(() => {
        window.onscroll = () => handleScroll(headerClassName);
    }, [headerClassName]); // IMPORTANT, This will cause react to update depending on change of this value

    return (
        <header id="header_menu" className={headerClassName}>
            <div className="right-menu float-right">
                <ul>
                    <li><Link to={'/'} >Home</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to={'/about'} >About Us</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to={'/contact'} >Contact Us</Link></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </header>
    );
}

export default HeaderMenu;
```

You can also test on [codepen](https://codepen.io/RB_Projects/pen/KKdyvBB?editors=0010)

Comment: I am learning the reach. So whatever i undersood from youtube I uploaded here.

Comment: Give me sometime to understand your answer

Comment: Class is added when scroll to bottom but when I go up the still showing class.

Comment: pls try again, the state value wasn't being updated in the `window.scroll` callback

Comment: Yes, I try again but still showing the menuscroll when reach at top.

Comment: check the codepen I added to my answer, it removes the classname when it get to the top

Comment: Please check my code here https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-almeida-t6q7w?file=/src/components/Header.js

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213025/discussion-between-rotimi-best-and-user9437856).

Comment: I have fixed it, what was missing was the array dependency in `useEffect`. Please take a look at my code now

Comment: Take a look at this codepen to test it out https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-keller-nyt10?file=/src/components/Header.js:552-587

Comment: Can you help me out in this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61624576/how-to-display-the-menu-list-when-clicking-on-the-hamburger-icon-in-react

Comment: Yes sure, I am looking at it